# How to call view from view.py in /admin url in django

Tags: python, django

How we can provide all objects of class which are stored in mysql data when application start with /admin url.

Answer (score 0):

By using a sql query. This is really basic stuff, like the other questions you have asked. Buy a book or use google, there's plenty of info out there on this stuff.

Comment: I know that but this is not my question, i want to get all sql data intially on /admin url. Beacuse we know to send any data from view.py firstly we should make request partcular view would call and that view would all data what i want before that call. But at  /admin url there is not any single request has gone to view.py.

Comment: @GoldenBird you asked how, I told you how. You could ass some fields that access this info on the admin page, but please please please read the django book before you ask __ANY__ more questions